# Why doesn't 'care' be used transitively when preceding a one-word object directly?

Tags: verbs

Why do you think 'care' does not used transitively preceding an object as in "He is caring her."

I want to know why you are feeling it incorrect, if you have good ideas to explain it clearly.

In my opinion, it does not make sense, because the meaning of the sentence cannot be fixed to be one thing.

That is to say, for me, it seems likely to be read largely as either his care is affecting her to feel tired of him, or he is affecting her to care, so I suppose by the ambiguity 'care' cannot be used transitively in such a construction and native speakers are feeling it unnatural, though they seem to know it is incorrect instinctively by the knowledge having been unwittingly accumulating for a lifetime.

Comment: So you are asking, "Why is English English, and not Something-that-isn't-English?". I'm sorry, languages are as they are, not as somebody thinks they ought to be.

Comment: A sentence can be ambiguous (address two things) and still be correct in the use of English. An example is "If the baby does not thrive on raw milk, boil it"...

Comment: @Colin Fine I can't help agreeing anymore with you, but I am the ideologist insisting that everthing comes from a reason, even though it is a subjective thing like a language. There should be an appropriate reason for it.

Comment: @EvaristeGalois: Good luck! (For clarity, I am using that wish in its common ironic meaning, something like "I don't think your plan has the slightest chance of success").

Comment: @Solar Mike However, I think, in the case you suggested, if a context were more added, the ambiguity could be resolved unlike care-sentence. There is nothing context to help care-sentence get rid of ambiguity.

Comment: @EvaristeGalois that was the whole point - the sentence is correct and ambiguous - adding more context changes the simplicity. The example you provided is incorrect whatever way you look at it.

Comment: @Solar Mike Then, do you think my reasoning is just nonsense? I think it is the only way to explain why it does not make sense.

Comment: and BTW **care** rarely (if ever) is used in continuous tenses (don't conflate with a gerund or a participle.)

Comment: @Mv Log:  **care** may not be used with the continuous tense when its meaning is "give a hoot", that is, "to feel some concern for or interest in something", but in other senses, "to feel (and show) concern for, to see to the well-being of",  it is used with the continuous tense.  *She is caring for that child as if it were her own.*

Comment: That should be *knowledge they have been unwittingly **accumulating** for a lifetime*.  You need the present participle in that clause, not the past participle. The verb **care** has been intransitive since the Old English period nearly 1500 years ago. It meant "to feel concern, sorrow, worry or anxiety".  We use words as they are used by the speakers whose world we are born into and so there is a remarkable degree of continuity in the midst of change.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo   Let's attempt to coin a neologism. What would you think having heard such a phrase: _He cares her off_ ? (by analogy with _to put off_)

Comment: @My Log Do you intend to say his care causes her off ? (To say differently, He has too much care for her to feel to want to be off him.)  I don't have a problem to understand what it means. I dare to say it can be acceptable because the meaning you want to say seems to be understandable without any ambiguity.

Comment: @Mv Log: That neologism makes no sense to me at all. I might wonder if I had misheard, and that the speaker had said **carries** or **scares**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo   But you wouldn't have any problem having heard "His overbearing care puts her off," would you? There seems to be just one step to my suggestion—first nobody understands it, then it's a new phrasal verb.

Comment: @Evariste Galois  Your understanding doesn't make it grammatical. Natural language is **not** a rational enterprise, it's hopeless to try and find any logic in it. You should try some constructed language if this is essential for you.

Comment: @Mv Log: Specious reasoning. In **overbearing care** the word **care** is a noun. It is not a verb.  That sort of reasoning puts me off.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  That's the way English is ))) A noun becomes a verb and vice versa. Only the lack of care in this world could explain the lack of **care (somebody) off** in English )))

Answer (score 5):

Because the verb "care" is intransitive.

As English is a natural language, the only reason "why" is historical. In this case, the older meanings of "care" are related to having a feeling: If you were happy, you "rejoiced"; if you were sad, you "cared" (This meaning is obsolete in modern English)

Since it used to mean "have an emotion" it wouldn't make much sense to "care somebody". Just like we can't say "I rejoiced her" or "I cried her" we can't say "I cared her".

Now "care" has lost that meaning and picked up new ones.  But the grammatical rule that "care" is intransitive has persisted.  Nobody planned this.

"He's caring her" is not correct English. If someone said this it would probably be understood to be an error for "He's caring for her", or "He cares about her", depending on context. It could not be understood to mean "His care is causing her to be tired" or "He is causing her to care".

Comment: Then, what do you think of my reasoning? Doesn't it make sense and be plausible at all?

Comment: And transitive also— _don't care what they say • doesn't care a damn_, 
_Would you care to dance?_

Comment: I don't care for your reasoning.  "care" could a transitive verb, meaning "care for". It wouldn't be particularly ambiguous.

Comment: @My Log Good suggestions! However, they are not of the case I subjected as a problem.

Comment: @Mv Log: I would not consider *I do not **care** what they say* to be an example of a transitive use of **care**. It is not at all the same as *I do not **like** what they say.*  I understand **what they say** in the **care** example to be a form of **whatever they may say**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary 11th Ed. disagrees with you on this issue.

Comment: @Mv Log: Reasonable people can disagree on the analysis (and there I'm being charitable).   I would compare it to German **was es sei**.  *I don't care what it is. I don't give a damn what it is.*  Would you consider **give a damn** a transitive verb there?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo **give a damn** is not a verb, but **give** is and it's transitive imo

Comment: @Mv Log: But **give a damn** is in exactly the same position as **care** in that pattern, and the phrase **give a damn** is synonymous with **care**.  But I don't think it's transitive either. That was a socratic question. What that sentence means is "I don't care, no matter what it may be."  **what it is** is not a direct object.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo  Synonymity is useless in parsing. In your example **give** has a direct object **a damn** (noun)

Comment: @Mv Log:In the **give a damn** sentence what is **what it is**?  It is not a direct object, since **damn** is the direct of object of **give**.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo A complement, I suppose: **I don't give a damn** (about) **what it is**